# Is there a natural Riemannian metric on the space of smooth immersions into a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

Let $N$ be a compact oriented smooth manifold, and let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Denote by $Imm(N,M)$ the space of smooth immersions $N\to M$. As explained for example [here](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ruiloja/Math519/compaan.pdf) , $Imm(N,M)$ is an open set of $C^\infty (N,M)$ with the $C^\infty$ topology, and so it is an infinite-dimensional Frechet manifold.

We can also define on $Imm(N,M)$ a distance defined by $d(f,g)=\sup_{p\in N} d(f(p),g(p))$ where the distance on the right hand term is the geodesic distance of $M$.

My question is: is there a natural way to define on $ Imm(N,M) $ an "infinite dimensional Riemannian metric"? And how are the $C^\infty $ topology, the possible infinite dimensional Riemannian metric and the sup distance defined above related? References treating this subject are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent space $T_f(Imm(N,M))$ is $\Gamma(f^*TM)$, the space of vector fields along $f$. The Riemannian metric on $M$ provides a natural inner product on  $\Gamma(f^*TM)$, for instance, 
$$
\int_N g(X, Y) dVol_{f^*(g)}
$$
where $g$ is the Riemannian metric on $M$, $dVol$ is the volume form, $X, Y$ are vector fields along $f$. I think, but did not check, that the corresponding distance functions yields the uniform topology on connected components of $Imm(N,M)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just reading this paper: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN362162050_0098/PPN362162050_0098___LOG_0021.pdf which defines exactly the same metric.